# Crystal Report - Load report failed for vs 2003 project

Tags: crystal-reports, iis-7.5, visual-studio-2003

I am using vs 2003 with bundled crystal report and asp v1.1

OS:server 2008 r2 iis 7.5

This is the error i am getting when trying to open reoprt
Report works fine on development system. problem occurs in Production system

I have tried many solution  found on net. Please help...!!

Also Report was developed using bundled crystal report software . is their any crystal report update needed on production system

this is the error i am getting

> Load report failed.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code. Exception Details:
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystaReports.EngineloadSaveReportException: Load
>   report failed.
>
> SOURCE ERROR:
>
> adp.Dispose()
>
> Dim MyReport As AbstractofResultsReport = New AbstractofResultsReport
>
> **MyReport.SetParametervalue("CurrYear". CurrYear)** ERROR OCCURS HERE
>
> MyReport.SetDataSource(ds)
>
> Dim os As System.IO.Stream
>
> Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VHSE\AbstractofResuttsRep.aspx.vb
>
> Version Information: Microsoft NET Framework Version:1.1.4322.2032;
>   ASP.NET Version:1.1.4322.2032

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a typo but:

`MyReport.SetParametervalue("CurrYear". CurrYear)`

Should most likely be:

`MyReport.SetParametervalue("CurrYear", CurrYear)`

Assuming you have defined CurrYear previously?